# Repair an indexedDB

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

Is there a way to guarantee the existence of object stores in an indexedDB without changing the version number?

Context:

One of my users has an indexedDB set to the same version as everyone else, but with no object stores. I've no idea how they did it so I can't predict if it will happen again and I don't know how widespread the problem could be out in the public arena.

I tried using the following code to rebuild the missing objectStore

```
    this.request = window.indexedDB.open(this.dbName, this.DB_VERSION);
    this.request.onsuccess = (event) => {
        const database = event.target.result;
        if (!database.objectStoreNames.contains(store)) {
                const newStore = database.createObjectStore(store, {keyPath: 'key'});
                newStore.createIndex('expiry_idx', 'exp');
        }
    }
```

but the browser is saying I can't run createObjectStore unless I am in the onupgradeneeded event. At this point the database is not being upgraded. This user and everyone else is on version 5. I could change the code to try to open v6 and force an upgrade that repairs it, but for all I know someone else could corrupt v6.

Comment: *Is there a way to guarantee the existence of object stores in an indexedDB without changing the version number?* Do you mean create? *Guaranteed the existence of* is the phrase I just couldn’t put well to understand.

Comment: Mind you, you are working with client browsers. Everybody’s browser behaves one weird way or another.

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon I mean create X if it does not exist, but do not try to create X if X already exists (because that would fail). So no matter what state the system was in before my code, I know for sure that at the end of the process there is exactly one objectStore called X

Comment: Okay makes more sense now. I remember there is a part of the API that returns a [DOMStringList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMStringList) of ObjectStores in a particular [Database](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBDatabase) currently opened. Check [IDBDatabase: objectStoreNames property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBDatabase/objectStoreNames)

Comment: Have you found out why the said user’s database had the same version with everyone else’s but still had no ObjectStores?

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon No idea. He's not the sort of person who would muck around in the browser console, but he could have cleared cache or local data.

Answer (score 2):

There is an extremely hacky way to do it, if the database is small enough. Read all the data into memory, delete the old database, create the new database with the correct object stores and the correct version, and then write all the data to it.

Comment: Since you are targeting multiple clients, this is a good way to reset every clients database to the same version (your preferred new version). One upvote from me 

Comment: None of the data is precious, all just cached data that would be rebuilt easily during use. I'd then be stuck with triggering it to wipe everything and know it was starting again

Answer (score 1):

Since you clarified that

> …guarantee the existence of object stores in an indexedDB without changing the version number?

here means

> create … if it does not exist

### I guess the answer is
No

Yes you can check if it exists using the [IDBDatabase: objectStoreNames property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBDatabase/objectStoreNames). It returns a [DOMStringList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMStringList) with which you can call the `contains()` method. But you [cannot create an object store (if it doesn’t already exist) without a version upgrade.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBDatabase/createObjectStore#examples)

> This method can be called only within a versionchange transaction. 
> [IDBDatabase: createObjectStore() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBDatabase/createObjectStore)